# How to Convert an Integer to a String without Integer.toString Function

Tags: java, recursion

This is an extension to a previous question of mine, but I'm required to do this problem without this function. I have to use recursion only. Any thoughts?

An example; 20A would be:

2 x 12^2 + 0 x 12^1 + 10 x 12^0 = 2 x 144 + 0 x 12 + 10 x 1 = 288 + 0 + 10 = 298

```
public class Duodecimal {
      public static String toBase12(int n) {
        if (n < 10)
            return Integer.toString(n);
        if (n == 10)
            return "A";
        if (n == 11)
            return "B";
        return toBase12(n / 12) + toBase12(n % 12);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Replace `Integer.toString(n)` with `"" + n`

Comment: I think you should come out with some attempt to solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

Well, you've figured it out for n == 10. Surely you can use the same technique for n == 9. If you want an alternate idea, imagine you have the string '0123456789AB'. String has a method to ask for the character at a given index. NOw, what digit is at position '9' in that string? What is at 10? Exactly. This method is `charAt`.

I bet you can finish this homework with this hint :)

Answer (score 0):

With a little thought,  you could extend this to convert any base from 2 thru 16.

1. Add a second parameter to the method and call it `base` or `radix`
2. Define a final String of `digits` as `"0123456789ABCDEF"`
3. Put in appropriate check(s) to ensure the `radix` is within an allowable range.